# how to convert a pipe delimited text file with multiple data lines to xml

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there is an accepted method to convert a Pipe delimited text file to XML using python. The delimited file I am looking to convert is in the format:\n

RECID|ATTN|CARE OF|STREET1|STREET2|STREET3|CITY|STATE|ZIP|COUNTRY|
RECIPIENT|Lexi||2226 S 106TH DR APT F3QI|||CHICAGO|IL|60644|UNITED STATES|

RECID|FRST NAME|MID NAME|LAST NAME|NM STR|SEX|DOB|PREFIX|SUFFIX|DSGTN|DBA|
RECIPIENTNAME|Kenneth|||Kenneth Cole|M|08241993|||Doctor||

the RECID line is like tag line or header line for the data below it. 
i am looking for xml conversion like this

```
**<RECIPIENT>**
     <ATTN>lexi</ATTN>
     <care_of></care_of>
     <STREET1>2226 S 106TH DR APT F3QI</STREET1>
     <STREET2></STREET2>
     <STREET3></STREET3>
     <CITY>Chicago</CITY>
     <STATE>IL</STATE>
     <ZIP>60644</ZIP>
     <COUNTRY>UNITED STATES</COUNTRY>
**</RECIPIENT>**
**<RECIPIENTNAME>**
    <FRST NAME>Kenneth</FRST NAME>
    <MID NAME></MID NAME>
    <LAST NAME></LAST NAME>
    <NM STR>Kenneth Cole</NM STR>
    <SEX>M</SEX>
    <DOB>08241993</DOB>
    <PREFIX></PREFIX>
    <SUFFIX></SUFFIX>
    <DSGTN>Doctor</DSGTN>
    <DBA></DBA>
**</RECIPIENTNAME>**
```

i did not find any code relating to this conversion. all the codes are considering first row in file as header

Comment: The pipe-delimited file seems to be a CSV file with pipe as the delimiter. You should use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html) module to read it.

Comment: thank you, i will need help with any modules that i can use to execute every line separately by creating a xml output for each line. 
I did see there are examples of creating xml files on same data but I have a different data in each line